# Is there a simpler way to calculate this MD5 hash?

Tags: c#, asp.net, md5

I'm working on implementing a hosted checkout, and the hosted checkout is supposed to redirect the user back to my website so that I can show a custom receipt page.

This is a sample querystring that I'd get back:

> trnApproved=0&trnId=10000000&messageId=71&messageText=Declined&authCode=000000&responseType=T&trnAmount=20.00&trnDate=9%2f23%2f2011+9%3a30%3a56+AM&trnOrderNumber=1000000&trnLanguage=eng&trnCustomerName=FirstName+LastName&trnEmailAddress=something_something%40gmail.com&trnPhoneNumber=1235550123&avsProcessed=0&avsId=0&avsResult=0&avsAddrMatch=0&avsPostalMatch=0&avsMessage=Address+Verification+not+performed+for+this+transaction.&cvdId=3&cardType=VI&trnType=P&paymentMethod=CC&ref1=9dae6af7-7c22-4697-b23a-413d8a129a75&ref2=&ref3=&ref4=&ref5=&hashValue=33dacf84682470f267b2cc6d528b1594

To validate the request, I'm supposed to remove `&hashValue=f3cf58ef0fd363e0c2241938b04f1068` from the end of the querystring, and then append a key. I then perform an MD5 hash of the entire string, and the result should be `33dacf84682470f267b2cc6d528b1594`, same as the original.

This is easy, except that a few of the fields are causing a problem for me. This is the code I use (taken from a dummy application, so you can ignore some of the bad coding):

```
// Split up the query string parameters
string[] parameters = GetQueryString().Split(new[] { "&" }, StringSplitOptions.None);
var querySet = new List<string>();

// Rebuild the query string, encoding the values.
foreach (string s in parameters)
{
    // Every field that contains a "." will need to be encoded except for trnAmount
    querySet.Add(param.Contains("trnAmount") ? param : UrlEncodeToUpper(param));
}

// Create the querystring without the hashValue, we need to calculate our hash without it.
string qs = string.Join("&", querySet.ToArray());
qs = qs.Substring(0, qs.IndexOf("&hashValue"));
qs = qs + "fb76124fea73488fa11995dfa4cbe89b";

var encoding = new UTF8Encoding();
var md5 = new MD5CryptoServiceProvider();
var hash = md5.ComputeHash(encoding.GetBytes(qs));

var calculatedHash = BitConverter.ToString(hash).Replace("-", String.Empty).ToLower();
```

This is the UrlEncode method I use.

```
private static string UrlEncodeToUpper(string value)
{
    // Convert their encoding into uppercase so we can do our hash
    value = Regex.Replace(value, "(%[0-9af][0-9a-f])", c => c.Value.ToUpper());
    // Encode the characters that they missed
    value = value.Replace("-", "%2D").Replace(".", "%2E").Replace("_", "%5F");
    return value;
}
```

This all works (until someone enters a character I haven't accounted for), except this seems more complicated than it should be. I know I'm not the only one who has to implement this HCO into an ASP.NET application, so I don't think the simple validation should be so complicated.

Am I missing an easier way to do this? Having to loop through the fields, encoding some of them while skipping others, converting their encoding to uppercase and then selectively replacing characters seems a little... odd.

Comment: Yay a GET request that changes state... Better hope Google has enough money to pay for all the stuff it's going to buy off your site!

Comment: @Blindy, changes state? Nothing gets changed on this request. We're just displaying a receipt to a user who will be authenticated.

Comment: Can you do a post instead of using the query string?

Comment: What does `GetQueryString()` do?

Comment: @Jacob, in the production site it just calls HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString, in my little dummy app it just calls that exact string.

Comment: @JonRaynor, not that I know of. It appears to be limited to a GET.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a better way to work with query strings:

```
var queryString = "trnApproved=0&trnId=10000000&messageId=71&messageText=Declined&authCode=000000&responseType=T&trnAmount=20.00&trnDate=9%2f23%2f2011+9%3a30%3a56+AM&trnOrderNumber=1000000&trnLanguage=eng&trnCustomerName=FirstName+LastName&trnEmailAddress=something_something%40gmail.com&trnPhoneNumber=1235550123&avsProcessed=0&avsId=0&avsResult=0&avsAddrMatch=0&avsPostalMatch=0&avsMessage=Address+Verification+not+performed+for+this+transaction.&cvdId=3&cardType=VI&trnType=P&paymentMethod=CC&ref1=9dae6af7-7c22-4697-b23a-413d8a129a75&ref2=&ref3=&ref4=&ref5=&hashValue=33dacf84682470f267b2cc6d528b1594";
var values = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(queryString);
// remove the hashValue parameter
values.Remove("hashValue");
var result = values.ToString();
// At this stage result = trnApproved=0&trnId=10000000&messageId=71&messageText=Declined&authCode=000000&responseType=T&trnAmount=20.00&trnDate=9%2f23%2f2011+9%3a30%3a56+AM&trnOrderNumber=1000000&trnLanguage=eng&trnCustomerName=FirstName+LastName&trnEmailAddress=something_something%40gmail.com&trnPhoneNumber=1235550123&avsProcessed=0&avsId=0&avsResult=0&avsAddrMatch=0&avsPostalMatch=0&avsMessage=Address+Verification+not+performed+for+this+transaction.&cvdId=3&cardType=VI&trnType=P&paymentMethod=CC&ref1=9dae6af7-7c22-4697-b23a-413d8a129a75&ref2=&ref3=&ref4=&ref5=

// now add some other query string value
values["foo"] = "bar"; // you can stuff whatever you want it will be properly url encoded
```

Then I didn't quite understand what you wanted to do. You want to calculate an MD5 on the result? You could do that and then append to the query string.

Comment: the problem is that I can't just remove the hashValue and do the hash, because before I do the hash I need to go through the fields and "fix" up the encodings on some of the characters from the response they've sent me.

Comment: @Brandon, what do you mean by *fix up the encoding of some characters*? Don't you have a real query string?

Comment: yes. When I call HttpContext.Current.QueryString I get the result I posted in my question. I can't do an MD5 hash on that querystring because it gives an incorrect result. I need to perform the modifications I mentioned in the question in order to get the right result. Basically, I can't use the querystring as-is, because it's not the same string that the HCO provider used to calculate their hash.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov, are you sure that `ParseQueryString` will guarantee that the variables will remain in the same order when you call `ToString()`?